# Ruby - how different are modules from classes?

Tags: ruby

Let me write down some difference between them as I know

1. Modules can't be instantiated, whereas classes can be
2. Multiple modules can be included / extended, whereas only one class can be inherited

Aside from the above mentioned two, I don't see any other differences between them

1. Both can have class level variables (@@)
2. Both can have class-instance level variables (@, initialized directly in the module/class)
3. Both can have instance variables (@, initialized inside the methods)
4. Both can have global variables ($)
5. Both can have methods that can be directly called using their names (prefixed with "self")
6. Both can have inner classes
7. A class that includes and extends a module has access to all its methods (non-private) which is the same as inheriting from a class does for the subclass

Leaving the multiple inheritance out, is the only difference between classes and modules are that of creating objects?

(I don't have a lot of experience in Ruby, just trying to get my head around the difference between classes and modules. Please feel free to point out anything that I might have missed)

Comment: Classes are modules. Your description is contradictory.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151505/difference-between-a-class-and-a-module

Comment: roughly the same as fruit is from apples (one is a special kind of the other)