# How to DRY duplicated Model Methods in Ruby on Rails, by Modules or Classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, module, dry

Hy. I'm new to Ruby on Rails and OOP.
I work on a little Scheduler, and want to DRY my Model Methods.
I red some about usage of Module and Class in Rails, but can't find out what is the best way.
[difference-between-a-class-and-a-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151505/difference-between-a-class-and-a-module)
[ruby-class-module-mixins](http://matt.aimonetti.net/posts/2012/07/30/ruby-class-module-mixins/)

*Example:*

Supposed i have 2 Models ( Datum and Person ). 
Each Model has an Attribute which store's a Date, but with different Attribute Name's.

I wrote the same Method for Date Validation in both Module's.

*My Models:*

```
class Datum < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr :start_date

 def validate_date
  # same validation stuff with self.start_at
 end
end
```

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr :birth_date

 def validate_date
  # same validation stuff with self.birth_date
 end
end
```

*Here is my attempt with a lib/ModelHelper and Datum Model:*

```
class Datum < ActiveRecord::Base
 include ModelHelper

 attr_accessible :start_at

 # Validations
 before_validation :validate_date, :start_at

end
```

```
module ModelHelper

 private

 def validate_date *var
  # validation stuff with birth_date and start_at 
 end
end
```

*Question:*
In my case, i think i need to assign a Parameter ( for each Model attribute, :start_at and :bith_date ). 
But i can't discover how.

**What is the best way to DRY my Models, with Module or Class ?**
**Why and How?**

Comment: I highly recommend you check out codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Incidentally, I recently published an answer on CodeReview.SE about custom Rails 4 validators: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/71435/reservation-validation/71496#71496

Comment: @Anthony My Question is not only for Code Review.
Its more about understanding Module and Class in Ruby on Rails, with an given Example.

Comment: @D-side thx for your comment, and your Answer is helpful. 
But it doesn't explain my Question.
**What is the best way to DRY my Models, with Module or Class ?**
**Why and ...?**
I AM PLEASED FOR MORE ANSWERS.

Comment: @stephanfriedrich in this specific context, `validate_date` could be factored out into a validator class. Then you'll only have declarations of attributes and validation rules. DRY enough.

Answer (score 0):

Just as @D-side said in the comments, your best option is to create a [Custom Validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators).

Create a **app/validators** directory and add a file with a name like **my_date_validator.rb** and content like this:

```
# EachValidator is a validator which iterates through the attributes given in the
# options hash invoking the validate_each method passing in the record, attribute
# and value.
#
# All Active Model validations are built on top of this validator.
#
class MyDateValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless value_is_valid? # <- validate in here.
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not a valid date")
    end
  end
end
```

and in your models just add:

```
class Datum < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :start_date, my_date: true
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :birth_date, my_date: true
end
```

The **my_date** stands for the first part of **MyDate**Validator class name.

If you name your validator:

- FooValidator then you use it in your model validations as foo.
- FooBarValidator then you use it in your model validations as foo_bar.
- MyDateValidator then you use it in your model validations as my_date.

Also, depending on what you want to validate you may want to look at this Gem:

https://github.com/johncarney/validates_timeliness

Comment: Adding some references here: the preferred place for app-specific validators is `app/validators`, https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide/blob/master/README.md#app-validators

Comment: Thanks for your Response. But why don't you use a Model?

Comment: Or in your Example / Rails Guide. What if 
i try to use more custom validators ( should i write for each Validator c Class )

Comment: Also i dont understand, what does my_date: true stand for ? 
And what If i run my validation how i mentioned ( before_validation :validate_date ) ?

Comment: Thank you @D-side I updated the answer based on your comment.

Comment: @stephanfriedrich my_date: true stands for "run MyDateValidator" for this attribute. If the validator class name is FooValidator then you write foo: true, if the name is FooBarValidator you write foo_bar: true