# Include module , how does it work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, include

By example :

```
module Feature
  def self.included(klass)
    puts "#{klass} has included #{self}!"
  end
end

class Container
  include Feature
end
```

can you explain me how module can manipulate klass ?

can't find any clear documentation about it.

regards.

Comment: What is exactly unclear to you?

Comment: how klass is transmitted to the module ? wath does 'included' method ?

Comment: Probably [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151505/difference-between-a-class-and-a-module) reference may help.

Comment: In the below link a good explanation of hook methods: `included`, `extended`, `prepended`, `inherited`, `method_missing` http://www.sitepoint.com/rubys-important-hook-methods

Comment: i didn't ... admin's action i think .  your link was really usefull , but maybe not enough to be an answer , but enough to be a great comment.anyway thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a documentation for `ActiveSupport::Concern`, they make a pretty good job of describing this and a "new" concern approach.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

Basically when you include a module, its methods are added as **instance** methods to the class you include them in. When you extend a module, they become **class** methods.

So what happens here is when you include `Feature` the `Container` gains an `included` class method which has access to the class itself (using `klass`). Thanks to this behaviour we can for example include (or extend) dependant modules.

Answer (score 2):

I think include is just a method. This is what I did in irb.

```
 > require 'pry'
 > module A
 >   def self.included klass
 >     puts "included"
 >   end
 > end
 > class B
 >   binding.pry
 >   include A
 > end
```

when it enter into pry, I just see this

```
pry(B)>  self.method(:include)
=> #<Method: Class(Module)#include>
```

so I think include is a method ,and guess included method is called when include is done. Sorry for this, I don't have any evident on this. Might have to read the ruby source code, because I ask for source_location, but got nil

```
 pry(B)> self.method(:include).source_location
 => nil
```

I think ActiveSupport::Concern is used to solve the dependency problem