# Converting data structures to other data structures

Tags: ruby, oop, coding-style, data-conversion

I often need to convert some kind of data into other data (usually strings, arrays and hashes). For example:

- input: `"a;simple;list"`
- `expected_output`: `[ { content: "a", length: 1 }, { content: "simple", length: 6 }, { content: "list", length: 4 } ]`

This can be done by:

```
input.split(";").map{|s| { content: s, length: s.size } }
```

but I want to use conversion at different places. So I need to provide encapsulated logic to achieve and reuse this. Three ways pop into mind:

1. Use a helper method (put a single method into a module):

   ```
   module Converter
     extend self
     def convert(input)
       input.split(";").map{|s| { content: s, length: s.size } }
     end
   end

   module Caller
     Converter.convert(input)
   end
   ```
2. Use a dedicated class with parameters:

   ```
   class Converter
     def initialize(input)
       @input = input
     end
     def convert
       @input.split(";").map{|s| { content: s, length: s.size } }
     end
   end

   module Caller
     Converter.new(input).convert
   end
   ```
3. Use refinements, using monkey patching to create a method on the data object but letting a caller decide if it should be included.

   ```
   module Converter  
     refine String do
       def convert
         self.split(";").map{|s| { content: s, length: s.size } }
       end
     end
   end

   module Caller
     using Converter
     input.convert
   end
   ```

I'm not satisfied with any of them, but the third option seems the cleanest because that is usually what you would do if you deal with custom objects. But it also feels wrong because it's  monkey patching light. What are your thoughts?

Comment: The third option is basically exactly how refinements are intended to be used.

Comment: Neither of those will give you `expected_output`.

Comment: You're right, I changed the `expected_output` keys all to symbols, now it should be right

Answer (score 1):

It's great that you are approaching this from an OO perspective.

I like a variation on your second suggestion, with a small difference-- use an object, but don't instantiate it.

```
class StringConverter
  def self.to_size_hash(string)
    string.split(';').map { |s| { content: s, length: s.size } }
  end
end


2.2.2 :001 > StringConverter.to_size_hash "a;simple;list"
 => [{:content=>"a", :length=>1}, {:content=>"simple", :length=>6}, {:content=>"list", :length=>4}]
```

As long as this class is only going to do one thing, once, I can't think of a good reason to persist it in memory.

The benefits of this approach are that you're encapsulating the logic in the `StringConverter` class, without writing another module (the first option in your question), or changing the expected behavior of the `String` class (the third option). It's a dedicated class for this transformation that you can use anywhere you need it.

Comment: What is the benefit of using a class method over a module function?

Comment: In this case, I don't think there's much of a difference, just personal preference. I was mainly suggesting a dedicated class (or module) to avoid refinements. Doing so preserves the behavior of `String`.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151505/difference-between-a-class-and-a-module) a good overview of the difference between a module and class in Ruby.