# difference between modules inside a class and class inside a modules in ruby

Tags: ruby, module

I think both are used for namespace. 
Modules are generally mixed into classes, right? So, what would be the purpose of defining a module inside a class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between a class and a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151505/difference-between-a-class-and-a-module)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking modules have two uses:

- Namespacing modules. When you nest stuff here and the module is intended only for specifying paths.
- Functional modules. When the module has actual functionality that is intended to be called directly on the module or the module is intended to be included/extended.

Classes should be used for functionality only, even though Ruby doesn't enforce it.

Trying to do something but the above (like use module for both namespacing and functionality <sup>(1)</sup> or use a class for namespacing <sup>(2)</sup>) will generally confuse you.

---

<sup>(1) Some will disagree pointing to the rails' module with instance methods that also holds another module, called `ClassMethods`. I think it would have been cleaner if there was a module with two modules - `ClassMethods` and `InstanceMethods` instead.</sup>

<sup>(2) Some will disagree. A probably valid case is if you try to emulate private classes from other languages (where the private class will be nested inside your public class).</sup>